# Owl Carousel No Fixed Width

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

so I'm trying to use [Owl Carousel](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/dist/owl.carousel.js) without a fixed width because I need a responsive Wordpress site with no fixed images or widths, otherwise it breaks my mobile views.

I tried uncommenting the lines in owlcarousel.js where `_width` and `_widths` are set, and that sort of worked, except the items were then not centered within the `.owl-stage`. When I tried to alter the dimensions of the `.owl-stage` the entire thing broke.

Can anyone give advice on how to do this? I just want a responsive deployment of Owl Carousel where the widths etc are relative, rather than fixed.

Comment: Does the demo on the [documentation homepage](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) do what you're expecting? It says it's responsive

Comment: @adriancarriger It behaves as I expect according to the documentation, but it isn't what I want. The responsive functionality doesn't help me because it appears to be prefaced on the amount of items being shown at a time, I want one item shown at all times, so a change in item count being shown doesn't help me. I simply want the slider to work without generating fixed widths on important elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c867ssu/)

## Set items to 1

To make the Owl Carousel 2 show a single responsive slide you need to set the number of items to 1 instead of the default 3 and there is no need to use the responsive options offered in [the docs](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html) because you always want to show a single slide.

## JavaScript

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items: 1
})
```

## Full Code

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items: 1
})
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: #4DC7A0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't maintain images aspect ratio.  is there an solution for this.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you use attribute `width` with unit %

```
$('.owl-carousel').attr("width", "100%")
```

With unit % width of carousel will responsive follow width of screen device.

Other, you can use css3 to responsive.Corresponding with width of screen device you set width different.

That all i know. if you want :

1. Always show 1 element : you should set width of  `owl-item` is 100% and width of `owl-carousel` is : 100% .Or always show 2,3,4,5,.... you should set width of `owl-item` is (100/2) %, (100/3)%, (100/4)%, ...
2. Corresponding with screen will show 4 for desktop, 1 for mobile :you show use breakpoint to set width. In other, you can try attribute `min-width` or `max-width` for `owl-item` to make it

Comment: I don't think that's right, I need to target the source code, specifically manipulation of `owl-item` and the containing stage.

Comment: So, you need set attribute `width` of `owl-item` with unit % instead of `owl-carousel`

Comment: No, because the container of `owl-item` has a width that is a multiple of all the items, so setting it relative to that wouldn't work, because it is bigger than any individual item. I tried setting it relative to the `owl-carousel` element, but then the items were not centered properly, i.e. I had two items showing up in the view where there should only be one.

Comment: Also, I'd rather not work against the source code with after-the-fact DOM manipulation, because this is not as reliable as changing the source code itself to get what I want onload.

Comment: In this case, t think you must change width for different breakpoint to responsive follow you

Comment: Why do a breakpoint specific fixed width? I just want it to be fluid... does that make sense?

Comment: See again my answer.That all t know. I hope it can help you